# Playframework [Java]: provision error (com.google.inject.ProvisionException)

Tags: java, playframework, swagger

we use swagger codegen and I'm trying to change the `swagger.json` in my application for a new release. I don't know why error's message show a class that it's not being used in this class. I traced the code inside `provideApplication` and in the end I found the `DefaultApplicationController` code and error line (`imp.healthcheck();`), but the interface already have this method definition.

The code compiles, but when I run my test I have the following error:

Test part:

```
 private Application provideApplication() {
  return new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
   .overrides(bind(Config.class).toInstance(configuration))
   .in(new Environment(Mode.TEST))
   .build();
 }

 @Before
 public void setUp() {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

   petId = "1234567891";

   server = Server.forRouter(components -> RoutingDsl.fromComponents(components)
  .GET("/foo/v1/bar/" + petId).routeTo(() -> response("pet.json"))
  .GET(PRODUCTS_PATH + "/pets/" + petId + "/cats").routeTo(() -> response("cats.json"))
  .build());
  setupConfiguration("http://localhost:" + server.httpPort());

  app = provideApplication();
}

@Test
public void shouldProcessRequestAndReturnPets() throws Exception {
 Pets expectedPets = readJson("pets.json", Pets.class);

 Result result = route(app,fakeRequest(
 routes.ApplicationApiController.listPets(petId)));

 assertEquals(Http.Status.OK, result.status());
 Optional<String> contentType = result.contentType();
 assertTrue(contentType.isPresent());
 assertEquals(MimeTypes.JSON, contentType.get());

 Pets actualPets = deserializeResult(result, Pets.class);
 assertEquals(expectedPets.get(0), actualPets.get(0));
}
```

Error:

```
[error] Test ApplicationIT.shouldProcessRequestAndReturnProducts 
failed: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see 
the following errors:
[error] 
[error] 1) No implementation for 
controllers.DefaultApiControllerImpInterface was bound.
[error]   while locating controllers.DefaultApiControllerImpInterface
[error]     for the 1st parameter of controllers.DefaultApiController. 
<init>(DefaultApiController.java:39)
[error]   while locating controllers.DefaultApiController
[error]     for the 5th parameter of router.Routes.<init> 
(Routes.scala:47)
[error]   while locating router.Routes
[error]   while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
[error]   while locating play.api.routing.Router
[error]     for the 1st parameter of 
play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init> 
(HttpRequestHandler.scala:222)
[error]   while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
[error]   while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
[error]     for the 6th parameter of play.api.DefaultApplication.<init> 
(Application.scala:236)
[error]   at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:235)
[error]   while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
[error]   while locating play.api.Application
[error]     for the 1st parameter of play.DefaultApplication.<init> 
(DefaultApplication.java:32)
[error]   at play.DefaultApplication.class(DefaultApplication.java:32)
[error]   while locating play.DefaultApplication
[error]   while locating play.Application
[error] 
[error] 1 error, took 9.662 sec
[error]     at 
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1028)
[error]     at 
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance
(InjectorImpl.java:1054) 
[error]     at 
play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf
(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:409)
[error]     at 
play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.$anonfun$instanceOf$3
(Injector.scala:118)
[error]     at 
play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.withContext
(Injector.scala:126)
[error]     at play.api.inject.ContextClassLoaderInjector.instanceOf
(Injector.scala:118)
[error]     at 
play.inject.DelegateInjector.instanceOf(DelegateInjector.java:22)
[error]     at play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build
(GuiceApplicationBuilder.java:156)
[error]     at 
ApplicationIT.provideApplication
(ApplicationIT.java:47)
[error]     at ApplicationIT.setUp(ApplicationIT.java:62)
[error]     ...
[error] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         ApplicationIT
[error] (aplication/test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests 
 unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 17 s, completed 18-abr-2018 13:01:13
```

Also, this is the class without implementation that error says:

```
 import swagger.SwaggerUtils;


 import swagger.SwaggerUtils.ApiAction;

 @javax.annotation.Generated(value = "com.telefonica.BaikalCodegen", 
 date = "2018-04-18T13:00:30.424+02:00")

 public class DefaultApiController extends Controller {

 private final DefaultApiControllerImpInterface imp;

 @Inject
 private DefaultApiController(DefaultApiControllerImpInterface imp) {
    this.imp = imp;
 }


 @ApiAction
 public CompletionStage<Result> healthcheck() throws Exception {
    imp.healthcheck();
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ok());

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DefaultApplicationController` needs to implement `DefaultApiControllerImpInterface`.

In your code `DefaultApplicationController` extends `Controller` and **NOT** `DefaultApiControllerImpInterface`